# How do I show information to users belonging to different groups (web) in modx

Tags: content-management-system, modx, modx-evolution

I have created a website using modx evolution v1.0.2.

The website that I have developed has 12 different types of users (categorized in groups). Each user will be shown a different price depending on the group to which he belongs.

Till now I have been able to fetch the group name of current logged in user (created a snippet for that), but how can I achieve the above mentioned functionality so that each user should be able to see only the price that I have coded according to his group.

For example:
**If a user is associated with the 'ocassional' group then he should be shown the price as , say, 50 bucks
and if a user is associated with the 'regular' group then he should be shown the price as, say, 40 bucks**

I can easily do this by coding a single snippet for every product's variant, but there are a lot of variants (more than 100 and growing).

I have created a resource(page) for every product and it's variant. Every variant has a price. It is this price that I want to be shown according to the logged in user group membership.

I hope I am able to explain my query clearly.

Please help me do this functionality.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really convinced that modx (as much as i love it) is a great solution for e-commerce sites.

However, the best solution might be to use the database to store the prices of variants per user group and retrieve them yourself using a snippet.

Comment: This solution still needs a lot of work. I have created a new solution by myself. Working.. but not a perfect one.